# Auto assistant is not working in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

After installing jboss 4.9.0 final in eclipse ctrl + space is not working if i remove jboss tool then it's working fine.
Auto assistant is not working I check all the possibilities

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) is your question, whether it is not working or do you want to know how to fix it? Have you checked the Eclipse Bugzilla? Please also add the version of Eclipse you are using.

Comment: JBoss Tools 4.9 might be too old for the Eclipse you have. Use the current version of Eclipse with the matching version of JBoss Tools: https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/overview.html

Comment: @Yeti This sound like an JBoss Tools issue, not an Eclipse issue.